# jQuery datepicker not submitting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

so this is my first try of fiddeling around with ruby and i am trying to do a blog type of entry, where i am given the current date by default and then i can enter text into another textfield.

I created a datepicker, and set the date to select the current date. It automatically shows the current date and when clicking on the field, i can select another, but when submitting the post, the date is not being processed.

If i create a text field and enter the date manually, it works.

This is my _form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(gym) do |f| %>
  <% if gym.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(gym.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this gym from being saved:</h2>


      <ul>
      <% gym.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <!--  <div class="field", align="center">
    <%= f.label :Date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Date %>
  </div> -->

  <div class="input", align="center">
   <%= f.label :Date %>
 <input id="Date" type="text" size="10" >
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#Date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', defaultDate: new Date});
    $( "#Date" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date );
   } );
  </script>

</div>

  <div class="field", align="center">
    <%= f.label :Workout %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Workout, size:"30x10" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions", align="center">
    <%= f.submit "Submit a  Workout" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my new.html.erb

```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
<body>
<h1>New Workout</h1>
<p id ="new_one" ><%= render 'form', gym: @gym %>
<p id ="new_two", align="center"><%= link_to 'Back', gyms_path, {:style => 'color:#FFF'} %>
</body>
```

And this is the index.html.erb that displays the data.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<body bgcolor="#D6EAF8">

</body>
<h1 align="center">Workouts</h1>

<table  cellpadding="10", align="center" >
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Workout</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody bgcolor= "#EBDEF0", align="center">
    <% @gyms.each do |gym| %>
      <tr align="center">
        <td><%= gym.Date %></td>
        <td><%= gym.Workout %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', gym %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gym_path(gym) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', gym, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<p id ="new_work", align="center"><%= link_to 'New Workout', new_gym_path, {:style => 'color:#FFF'}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use form helper to create text_field, rails will create a text field input with id is **model_name**_**field_name**

Example: When I create a form for user

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will create a text field:

```
<input type="text" id="user_name" name="user[name]">
```

When add datepicker:

```
$("#user_name").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', defaultDate: new Date})
```

By another way, you also can create a text field input with custom id:

```
 <%= f.text_field :name, id: "my_input_id" %>
```

And

```
$("#my_input_id").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', defaultDate: new Date})
```

Hope I can help.

Comment: Thank you alot, i was able to fix my problem with your instructions.